# Django-mptt different order based on level

Tags: python, django, django-mptt, comments

I'm trying to make a threaded commenting system based on django-mptt.
The problem that I'm having is that the order of the comments cannot be changed according to their level.

What I am trying to achieve is a system in which "first level comments" are in ascending order based on submission date , while "nth level comments" (i.e. replies) are ordered in the opposite direction (check for example the youtube commenting system).

I have the order of insertion defined like this:

```
class MPTTMeta:
    order_insertion_by=['-submit_date']
```

and the `recursetree` `templatetag` to render the tree with the comments.

Is there any solution to set the order of insertion (or display) based on the level of each comment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer this question myself.

To get the "children" sorted in a order different from the "roots" I added:

```
        childlist = list(node.get_children())
        childlist.sort(key=lambda x: x.submit_date, reverse=False)
```

in the class `RecurseTreeNode` that can be found in the `mptt_tags.py` file.